# emacs process in background without `&`

Tags: shell, emacs

Hi I use emacs as my default editor. I would like emacs to run a process in the background from the shell without typing the`&` at the end 
How do I customize that?

gaurish108 ~: emacs hello.cpp &

[1] 3889

gaurish108 ~:

Comment: If you forget to type `&` you can generally interrupt a foreground process with `C-z` and then type `bg` to restart it in the background (or `fg` to restart in the foreground again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Burton Samograd said, this is part of the shell syntax.  If you want to hide it, try saving this in something like `emacs.sh`

```
emacs "$@" &
```

Then, `chmod +x emacs.sh`, and as long as `emacs.sh` is in a directory on your PATH, you should be able to run emacs as

```
emacs.sh filename
```

Answer (score 2):

I always do

```
 emacs --daemon
```

which actually using a very cool emacs feature where emacs runs as a server.

You then connect via

```
 emacsclient -nw       ## text mode, say via ssh on text connect
```

or

```
 emacsclient -c &      ## new x11 windows, return to prompt
```

and the best part is that the actual buffers remain active in the background emacs server while the front-end clients can go up or down --- stateful editing, and particular for modes with sessions (shell, SQL, R, ...) it makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

That irritating & is how you run a process in the background from the shell.  This is so you get your command prompt back after you run a program.  There is no way around it, it's just shell syntax.

Comment: Then is it possible to customize the shell syntax?

Comment: No, you cannot customize that part of the shell syntax.  You could hide it in a small script if it really bothers you.